# assigning onclick events to multiple spans using JS not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 spans, valued 0, 1, and 2. When you click on one, I want to alert its value. With my current code, they all alert *"length."* I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
<style>
.text{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
</style>

<span class='text'>0</span>
<span class='text'>1</span>
<span class='text'>2</span>

<script>
var textSpans=document.querySelectorAll('span.text');
for (i in textSpans)
{
    textSpans[i].onclick=function() {alert(i);};   
}
</script>
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bP88Z/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var textSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span.text');

for (i in textSpans) {
    textSpans[i].onclick = function(e) {
        alert(e.target.innerHTML);
    };   
}
```

The variable `e` is the mouse event. This will alert the contents of the target element of the click.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/NuQX2/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working, is because you are not using closure.

A closure is the local variables for a function - kept alive after the function has returned. So, in your original example, the last "i" left in the function scope is a "2". SO, to create a "closure" around each iteration of the "i", try using an anonymous function to "enclose/closure" the variable..

http://jsfiddle.net/bP88Z/4/

```
/* not a fan of 'i in ..." with arrays

An array is iterated using:

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
   //do stuff with a[i]

An object being used as an associative array is iterated using:

for (var key in o)
 do stuff with o[key] */
```

---

```
var textSpans=document.querySelectorAll('span.text');
for (i=0;i<textSpans.length;i++)
{
    (function(v){
        textSpans[v].onclick=function() {alert(v);};  
    }(i));
}
```